# SQL SSMS Window Dissappear

Tags: sql-server, ssms

When I open `SSMS`, I choose windows authentication, but the window just goes away; it doesn't say I'm not allowed.
I've accessed these db servers before, the exact same way, and it has worked.  Now, the window just goes away. According to **Task Manager** `SSMS` is still running but there is no window of any size at all and I've tried more than one server; I've also logged off and back on to the relevant machine with `SSMS` as well.
Has anyone ever seen any behavior like this?  Is there a way to "maximize" the window? Is my `SSMS` in need of repair?

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on the window in Task Manager on the application tab and choosing maximize?

Comment: That works.  The window had just gone off screen.

Comment: For a while, it looked like I'd have to ask for a re-install!

Comment: @dsolimano if you wish, promote your comment to an answer and I'll select it as the answer!  Thanks.  Simple but effective.

Comment: Done.  Though looking at this question, I wonder if it would be better off on SuperUser . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried right clicking on the window in Task Manager on the application tab and choosing maximize?  That usually works for me.